# Row index by change in column value?

Tags: numpy, triggers

Having array like this :

```
[[0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]
 [0 1 1]
 [1 0 0]]
```

how do I pick the row indexes where a column for the first time becomes 1.
Because there are 3 columns I have to get 3 row indexes.

In this case : 0,1,3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argmax` with `axis==0`:

```
ind = arr.argmax(axis=0)
ind.sort() # sort if needed
ind
```

Output:

```
array([0, 1, 3])
```